# Old JavaScript dates have weird timezones

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Consider this old date:

```
> new Date("0001-01-01")
Date Mon Jan 01 0001 00:17:30 GMT+0017 (Central European Standard Time)
```

**I was surprised by the date's timezone.**
I tried googling for "Central European Standard Time" but could not find more information about it.

What does this timezone tell me?
I interpret it as: in the year 1, my position on earth had timezone GMT+0017 (so plus 17 minutes and 30 seconds actually).

Is this a correct interpretation?
Where can i find more information about this; is this behavior defined somewhere?

Comment: For example, 1901 had “irregular” transitions (some number of minutes depending on location) between summer and normal time.  Check the history of time zones [here](https://tzexplorer.org/#/history)

Comment: They come from "LMT" (Local Mean Time) entries for each time zone in the IANA TZ Database sources.

Comment: Regarding the timezone name, according to [*ECMA-262*](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) timezone names are implementation dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 1 May, 1892, Belgium replaced its BMT time zone with today's standard time zone (WET). This involved setting the clocks backward by 17 minutes and 30 seconds.

See:

- [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/belgium/brussels?year=1892&lang=en).
- [worldtimezone.com](https://www.worldtimezone.com/standard-time-zone-chart-of-world-1894.html)

Comment: Thanks! That's what i was looking for but could not find it